Android LocationManager not returning users location
This is a React Native app but in a Android Native module.
I am using the Android LocationManager to get the users current location via GPS but it is returning [0.000000,0.000000]
Location permissions are granted. And I can access the users location in React Native code using the Geolocation services, so this appears to only be an issue with native android code.
I have tried using network as a provider with the same result.
val startingLocation = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        sendErrorToReact("Start Loc: $startingLocation")

